# Firebase Cloud Functions - Send push notification to multiple users doesn’t reach all of them

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a creation trigger on "posts" and send a push notification to all users of the app. The thing is that some testers report that they do not get every push. I watch the logs and no exception is caught!

Here's the code:

```
async function sendPushNotificationsForNewPost(postId, posterId, posterUsername) {
    try {
        const usersQuerySnapshot = await admin.firestore()
                                                .collection("users")
                                                .select(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), "deviceToken")
                                                .get()

        // -----------------------
    
        let messages = []

        for (const document of usersQuerySnapshot.docs) {
            const deviceToken = document.data().deviceToken ?? ""

            if (deviceToken.length > 0 && posterId != document.id) {
                const title = posterUsername
                const body = "just dropped a new music video"

                // ----------------------------

                const payload = {
                    notification: {
                        title: title,
                        body: body
                    },
                    apns: {
                      payload: {
                        aps: {
                            sound: "pushPop.m4a"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    data: {
                        type: "NewPost",
                        postId: postId
                    },
                    token: deviceToken
                }
            
                messages.push(payload)

                if (messages.length >= 500) {
                    await admin.messaging().sendEach(messages.splice(0, 500))
                }
            }
        }

        // ----------------------------

        if (messages.length > 0) {
            await admin.messaging().sendEach(messages)
        }
        
        return Promise.resolve()
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error)
        return Promise.resolve()
    }
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Is it an `async` issue?

Comment: First step would be to stop ignoring errors in the code. Reading log files is a great idea, but not a good way to handle errors. If your code catches an error, it should return a rejected promise with the error message - not a resolved promise. So: `} catch (error) {  return Promise.reject(error) }`.

Comment: Your code also complete ignores the response that `sendEach` returns, which may contain information on happened with the tokens that didn't receive the message. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.messaging.messaging.md#messagingsendeach for the return value of `sendEach`.

Comment: Great idea checking the response! Will try it now. Why shouldn’t I return a resolved promise? Does it make a difference?

Comment: Also is the use of `sendEach` with multiple batches correct here?